# Can't log in to Stack Overflow

Tags: support, login

For some reason I can't log in to Stack Overflow. When I click "log in" no OpenID provider icons appear. If I log into meta and then go back to stackoverflow, I'm "half" logged in: I get the usual bar with my name, rep, etc at the top, but stackoverflow thinks I'm logged out when I try to answer questions, and clicking on the "stackexchange" icon in the top bar does absolutely nothing.

How do I fix this problem? I've tried clearing my cookies but that didn't help.

I'm using Firefox and have never had a problem logging in before today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no repro -- I suggest clearing your browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

The only time I've had problems logging in with OpenID is when I turned off JavaScript, either within Firefox options or NoScript. Any chance that one of those might be causing your login problems?

Comment: I don't think so, because Meta is working fine for me (including logging in and other Javascript features)